# Complete list of Batei Dinim

Tags: halacha

Is this the most complete list of Batei Dinim outside the land of Israel?
https://kosherdelight.com/International_Directory_of_Rabbinical_Courts.shtml#1

Also, does anyone have a complete list of Batei Dinim in Israel? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a list compiled by the Israeli Rabbinate for Conversions which are done by Batei Dinim or recognised Rabbonim.  It includes Batei Dinim outside of Israel.

[https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/beit_din_in_world/he/רשימת%20בתי%20דין%20לגיור%20בעולם.pdf](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/beit_din_in_world/he/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D.pdf)

This one is for divorces [https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/beit_din_gitin/he/רשימת%20בתי%20דין%20מוכרים%20לגיטין%20בעולם.pdf](https://www.gov.il/BlobFolder/reports/beit_din_gitin/he/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D.pdf)

Comment: God bless you, thank you